# Windows Batch - Get the second line from file and save it

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, io

I have a .csv file (source.csv) which has the following contents:

```
_Name_;_Id_
IQ-000011;a0A4E000001m9UeUAI
IQ-000010;a0A4E000001m9EhUAI
IQ-000009;a0A4E000001m7v5UAA
```

What I want is either to get the **second line** (the one starting with `IQ-000011`) to be **appended** to another file (target.csv) or a *new file* to be created which consists of the first *two lines* (The `_Name_;_Id_` header + the `IQ-000011` line). This has to be done through batch on a Windows 10 machine.

I have tried using `set /p` and the script below but it didn't work correctly. I want to do it **without** `set /p`. How do I accomplish that?

This is the script I tried using:

```
3<source.csv (
set /p line1= <&3
set /p line2= <&3
)
echo %line2% >> target.csv
```

Comment: You have not explained what you mean by it didn't work correctly.  Regardless of that I am not understanding why you are trying to use file stream 3.  Why don't you just get rid of the `3` and `<&3`?  Your other option is to use a `FOR /F` command to read the source file.

Comment: I tested your code and it most certainly does output the `11` record to the target file.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how it would look like with the `FOR /F` command?

Comment: Do you not see all the answers below that are using the `FOR /F` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell by your question, but is this what you're trying to achieve?

```bat
@Set "line2="&((Set/P "="&Set/P "line2=")<"source.csv") 2>Nul
@If Defined line2 (Set/P "=%line2%"<Nul&Echo=)>>"target.csv"
```

Because you could probably do that like this from a batch file, without using `Set /P`:

```bat
@For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ("source.csv")Do @(Echo=%%A)>>"target.csv"&Exit/B
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a command that will produce the first data line of the .csv file.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('powershell -NoL -NoP "(Get-Content '.\source.csv')[1]"') DO (SET "LINE2=%%~a")
ECHO LINE2 is set to %LINE2%
```

Another way that might be more obvious is to use `Select-Object` to get the desired line.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('powershell -NoL -NoP "Get-Content '.\source.csv' | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1"') DO (SET "LINE2=%%~a")
```

Of course, if the script is written in PowerShell, it is easier and more clear.

```
$line2 = (Get-Content '.\source.csv')[1]
$line2 = Get-Content '.\source.csv' | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1
```